# How to specify unstructured covariance matrix and custom estimate statements in lme4?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

My data involves a DV (work) measured on 7 participants under three conditions (Control, Sleep or Deprived). Two of the conditions are counterbalanced (they completed the condition Sleep first then Deprived or Deprived first then Sleep). This is included under `Order` by 1 or 2, respectively. An example of my dataset is:

```
Individ <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Jude", "Jude", "Jude", "Tony", "Tony", "Tony", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "John","John", "John", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry"),
                      Condition = c("Control", "Sleep", "Deprived", "Control", "Sleep", "Deprived", "Control", "Sleep", "Deprived", "Control", "Sleep", "Deprived", "Control", "Sleep", "Deprived", "Control", "Sleep", "Deprived", "Control", "Sleep", "Deprived"),
                      Order = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                      Work = c(400, 250, 180, 500, 300, 450, 600, 512, 300, 500, 450, 200, 402, 210, 130, 520, 310, 451, 608, 582, 600))
```

I am interested on the effect of each `Condition` on `Work` and individual responses to these. I could (if this is the correct syntax) model this in `lme4` through the following code, where `xVarCond2` and `xVarCond3` are dummy variables for the two conditions:

```
lmer(Work ~ Condition + (1|Participant) + (0 + xVarCond2 + xVarCond3|Participant), data = Individ)
```

However, how do I specify an unstructured covariance matrix in the above model and generate custom estimate statements, like SAS does?